# sent string into function in other files c++

Tags: c++

How I can sent string variable into function in other file?
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include "headers.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
   string a;
   cout<<"Type:"<<endl;
   cin>>a;
   other(a);
    getch();    
    return( 0 );
}
```

headers.hpp:

```
#ifndef HEADERS_HPP
#define HEADERS_HPP

void other(string a);

#endif
```

function.cpp:

```
#include "headers.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void other(string a){
     cout<<a;}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. Do you know solution?

Comment: You want a solution but what exactly is the problem? "it doesn't work" doesn't really shed any light on the problem.

Comment: Well, looking into my glass ball, I see that it doesn't work becase neither headers.cpp nor function.cpp include <string>

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying it does not compile, you have to move the `#include <string>` from **main.cpp** into **headers.hpp**

Comment: Still doesn't work. ERROR: `string' was not declared in this scope

Comment: either replace the 'string' with 'std::string' or move the line 'using namespace std;' from function.cpp into headers.hpp